# add a column based on unlike value in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column of data where the value is attributed to a different row with one id that is the same, and the other id is not the same.  The data is below.

```
class_id  student  score  other_score
1         23       87     93
1         27       93     87
2         14       77     90
2         19       90     77
```

The other_score column is what I am looking to achieve, given the first three coulmns.  I have already tried:
`df$other_score = df[df$class_id == df$class_id & df$student != df$student,]$score`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be under complicating it but if there is always just two kids, sum after group by then remove score

```
library(dplyr)
output = df %>%
  group_by(class_id) %>%
  mutate(other_score = sum(score)-score)

output
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   class_id [2]
  class_id student score other_score
     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1        1      23    87          93
2        1      27    93          87
3        2      14    77          90
4        2      19    90          77
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `lead` and `lag`, and to retain the non `NA` value, whatever that might be:

```
library(dplyr)
output <- df %>%
    group_by(class_id) %>%
    mutate(other_score <- ifelse(is.na(lead(score, order_by=student)),
                                 lag(score, order_by=student),           
                                 lead(score, order_by=student)))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `setdiff` is to ignore the current index (`row_number()`) and select the `score` from remaining index.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(class_id) %>%
  mutate(other = score[map_dbl(seq_len(n()), ~setdiff(seq_len(n()), .))])

#  class_id student score other_score
#     <int>   <int> <int>       <int>
#1        1      23    87          93
#2        1      27    93          87
#3        2      14    77          90
#4        2      19    90          77
```

---

If you have more than two value in each `class_id` use

```
setdiff(seq_len(n()), .)[1])])
```

which will select only one value or you could also do

```
sample(setdiff(seq_len(n()), .))[1])])
```

to randomly select one value from the remaining `score`.

Comment: can you explain what the ~setdiff(seq_len(n()), .)) does?

Comment: @theofficefan12 For every row it drops the current row index. For example, if like in your example there are two rows in each group. for 1st row it would do `setdiff(1:2, 1)`, for second row it would do `setdiff(1:2, 2)`.